# Why does ModalRoute return null?

Tags: flutter, dart, parameter-passing

I want to pass a String to the next page using named parameters and ModalRoute, but I just receive "null" and not the data. Can somebody please explain what went wrong?

Here I want to push the information to the next page:

```
child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: filteredCitys.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                filteredCitys[index].toilettenanzahl == '0'
                                    ? Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/error')
                                    :
                                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/toilet', arguments: {
                                  'cityName': filteredCitys[index].ort,
                                });
                              },
```

Inside the build method of "toilet" I try to get the data:

```
Map ortData = {};

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    ortData = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    print(ortData);
```

But the result is just

```
I/flutter ( 8471): null
I/flutter ( 8471): null
```

This is my RoutGenerator

```
class RoutGenerator {
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute (RouteSettings settings) {
    final args = settings.arguments;

    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => Navigation());
      case '/home':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => Home());
      case '/city':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => CityCard());
      case '/toilet':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => ToiletCard());
      case '/error':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => ErrorPage());
      case '/map':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => ToiletMap());
      case '/impressum':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => Impressum());
      case '/kontakt':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => Kontakt());
      case '/info':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => Infos());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: show router or onGenerateRoutes

Comment: I edited the Question with my RoutGenerator

Comment: I think you need to add `settings: settings` parameter to every MaterialPageRoute

Comment: That solved it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by passing settings argument on MaterialPageRoute

```
MaterialPageRoute generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
 return MaterialPageRoute(
 settings: settings,
 builder: (context) {
  switch (settings.name) {
   case '/home':
    return const Home();
    //rest of your navigation case
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ortData = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments;
```

Comment: It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer. @Jay Smoke .